# Filtering using dropdown based on the uniq event name

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

i would like to add a filtering for my records of my table based on the value that I selected on my dropdown.Btw, I am using `power-select`. This is how my template looks like

```
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Event Name
        {{#power-select options=uniqEventName placeholder="Selecet Event Name" onchange=(action "selectEventName") as |eventName|}}
          {{humanize-string eventName capitalize=true}}
        {{/power-select}}
      </th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      {{#each modelNames as |modelName|}}
        <td>{{modelName.eventName}}</td>
        <td>{{modelName.updatedAt}}</td>
      {{/each}}
    </tr>
  </table>
```

And on my `route.js` this is how it looks like

```
 model() {
  const { date } = this.paramsFor('dashboard.route-name');
  return this.queryModel(date);
 },

 setupController(controller) {
   this._super(...arguments);

   const { date } = this.paramsFor('dashboard.route-name');
   controller.set('selectedDate', date);
 },

 queryModel(date) {
   date = date || moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD');

   return this.store.query('modelName', {
    filter: {
      'created-at:between': `${date} 00:00:00,${date} 23:59:59`
    },
      sort:    'updated-at'
   });
  }
```

and on my `controller.js` I have the following below

```
 import Ember from 'ember';

 export default Ember.Controller.extend({
   modelNames:    Ember.computed.alias('model'),
   eventNames:    Ember.computed.mapBy('modelNames', 'eventName'),
   uniqEventName: Ember.computed.uniq('eventNames'),

   actions: {
    selectDate(date) {
      this.transitionToRoute({ queryParams: { date }});
    },

    selectEventName(eventName) {
      console.log(eventName);
    }
  }
 });
```

My question is `How would I filter my records based on the eventName that I selected on my dropdown?` Any suggestions and approach is much appreciated, hoping someone could help as I am still noob on ember. Thank you

This is my `power-select`

```
 {{#power-select options=uniqEventName placeholder="Selecet Event Name" onchange=(action "selectEventName") as |eventName|}}
   {{humanize-string eventName capitalize=true}}
 {{/power-select}}
```

Answer (score 1):

First change the `onchange` action to let it set the selected event `onchange=(action (mut selectedEvent))`

Then you define a computed property:

```
filtered: Ember.computed('modelNames', 'selectedEvent', function(item) {
  return this.get('modelNames').filterBy('eventName', this.get('selectedEvent'));
})
```

BTW: I see your code does a transition programmatically when change selected date, you can use query params with `refreshModel` flag set to `true`. That would refresh the route dynamically when the date changes. For more info: https://guides.emberjs.com/v3.0.0/routing/query-params/#toc_opting-into-a-full-transition

Comment: I understand and I do appreciate for the answer you have given me and it is very helpful. However, what If i have multiple dropdown filtering? I will have a multiple `filtered` computed property? Is there any filtering that can be figured on the `model` hook?